# az storage blob copy subdirectories

Tags: azure, command-line-interface

I have a command in which I am copying an *entire* container, which is superfluous for my needs. The command is:

```
az storage blob copy start-batch \
--source-account-name ${san} \
--source-account-key ${key} \
--source-container ${sc} \
--account-name ${an} \
--account-key ${ak} \
--destination-container ${dc}
```

However, there is a subfolder in ${sc}, such as ${sc}/subdir1, or perhaps even ${sc}/subdir1/subdir2 where I would like to grab these files. However, doing this in the cli:

```
az storage blob copy start-batch \
--source-account-name ${san} \
--source-account-key ${key} \
--source-container ${sc}/subdir1/* \
--account-name ${an} \
--account-key ${ak} \
--destination-container ${dc}
```

This says there is no match found, because the source container is, simply, ${sc}. If I try the command without the '*', I get an error about:

```
The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server.
```

How can I glob subdirectories for this sort of command? I know there are matching patterns, but I need to go one, or perhaps two, directories (blobs) deeper to grab the files desired.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `azcopy` command to copy a subfolder in **Azure Storage account**. The **recursive=true** flag is used to indicate that all files and subdirectories within the specified directory should be recursively copied to the destination container in **Azure storage account**.

You can generate a **Shared Access Signature** token in the **Storage account** by following these steps.

**Azure Portal > Storage Account > select your storage account > Shared access signature**

[image]

**Az copy command to copy subfolder**

```
azcopy copy "https://<storageaccountname>.blob.core.windows.net/container1/<Tesfolder2><Storageaccountsastoken>"  "https://<storageaccountname>.blob.core.windows.net/container2<Storageaccountsastoken>" --recursive==true
```

**Output:**

[image]

If you want to copy entire container to another container in azure storage account, use below command.

```
azcopy copy "https://<storageaccountname>.blob.core.windows.net/container1<Storageaccountsastoken>"  "https://<storageaccountname>.blob.core.windows.net/container2<Storageaccountsastoken>" --recursive==true
```